# How do I use conditional formatting in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I am a basic user of Excel.  I have an automated spreadsheet with 2 columns: 1 column with usernames and the other with Active Directory groups.

For example:

```
Group1    User1
Group2    User1
Group2    User2
Group2    User3
Group1    User4
```

My pivot table has the AD Group names at Column Headers and the 1st column (A) is a list of the users.

```
      Group1   Group2  
User1
User2
User3
```

I would like to put an "X" in a matrix form.

```
       Group1   Group2   
User1    X         X
User2              X
User3              X
User4    X
```

How would I automatically do this?

Thank you,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the pivot table normally to show the results you require:

Here's a screen dhot of the settings

[image]

Then select the Counts area and set `Number format` to `custom`, `X;X;` to display `X`'s rather than numbers